# How to get a users avatar when I only have the name of the user?

Tags: laravel

I want to get the users avatar from my users table when I only have the users name from my posts table.

I've tried to make a foreach loop like this:

```php
$posts = Post:all();

foreach($posts as $post) {
  $user = User::where('name', $post->creator)->get();
}

return view('welcome')->with('posts', $posts)->with('user', $user);
```

Then looping it in my view like this:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
 @foreach($user as $creator)
<span>{{ $creator->avatar }}</span>
<span>{{ $post->post_url }}</span>
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

But its returning me the same avatar image, not the avatar image from the user which belongs to the post.

My user model:

```php
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'avatar', 'full_name', 'slug'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'creator','name');
    }
```

Post model:

```php
protected $fillable = [
        'creator', 'post_url', 'game', 'likes', 'created_at'
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

My web.php:

```php
Route::get('/', 'PostController@main_page');
```

My function main_page:

```php
public function main_page()
{
   $posts = Post:all();

   foreach($posts as $post) {
     $user = User::where('name', $post->creator)->get();
   }

   return view('welcome')->with('posts', $posts)->with('user', $user);
}
```

Can someone enlighten me and bring me to the right path? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override the `$user` variable for each post. Save it in an array instead:

```php
   $posts = Post::all();
   $users = [];

   foreach($posts as $post) {
     $users[$post->id] = User::where('name', $post->creator)->get();
   }

   return view('welcome')->with('posts', $posts)->with('users', $users);
```

Then in the view:

```php
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <span>{{ $users[$post->id]->avatar }}</span>
    <span>{{ $post->post_url }}</span>
@endforeach
```

But a better solution would be to save the `id` of the user inside the `posts` table, not just the name, and [add a relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). Then the code would be:

```php
   $posts = Post::with('user')->get();

   return view('welcome')->with('posts', $posts);
```

*`with('user')` [preloads the relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), to not generate too many queries. If you only need the avatar you could make it even better performing by using `with('user:avatar')` instead.*

The view would then look like this:

```php
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <span>{{ $post->user->avatar }}</span>
    <span>{{ $post->post_url }}</span>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I'm quite new to laravel and tried to add a relationship to my user model like this: public function avatar() {
        return $this->belongsTo('name', 'avatar');
    } but I get an error called Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all() what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Happy to help. You need a `user()` relationship on the `Post` class. You can take [the example from the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) and replace `Post` with `User` and `Comment` with `Post`.

Comment: Or you can do it by name as in your updated question. :-) But you also need to define the [inverse relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) on the `Post` model.

Comment: Thank you! I've already a user() relationship on my Post model which returns 
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class); is this correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me. Just be aware that this will throw an error if there is no user with the defined name (e.g. if the user changed it). To prevent that you can either use `optional($post->user)->avatar` (will print nothing if user not found) or by defining the relationship with the ID.

Comment: I'm using the id now, I shouldnt get any problems with that I think :) But still my issue with Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all() persists. Do I have to define the Builder somewhere?

Comment: I just discovered that you have a typo in `Post:all()`: there should be two colons `Post::all()`.

Comment: Ah, my fault. It's supposed to be `Post::with('user')->get()` not `all()`. Will update my answer.

Comment: Now I'm getting Trying to get property of non-object when I use $post->user->avatar .. thats weird, I've tried simmilar things before, I guess it was $post->creator->avatar which didnt work either.

Comment: Did you already add a `creator_id` or `user_id` field to the `posts` table? And can you update the question with the new relationship?

Comment: instead of the name in my creator field its just the users id which is getting inserted now. will update the question.

Comment: By default, Laravel looks for a `{{MODEL}}_id` column in the table (in this case `user_id`). To override that pass the correct column name: `$this->belongsTo(User::class, 'creator');`

Comment: ooh, that makes sense. but I'm still getting the same error. the solution is probably quite easy but I still cant figure it out. sorry for asking so much, and I'm really thankful for helping me out here! :)

Comment: What is `post->user` if you add `dd($posts)` to the controller?

Comment: You're probably wanting the relation part, inside is this: #relations: array:1 [▼
        "user" => null
      ]

Comment: Got it! I had to run php artisan migrate:refresh because I had one post which had the name in the creator field, not the users id. Now its working correctly, no errors and my image is getting displayed. Wow! Thanks for your help, really appreciate it. Have a great day! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know sql you can send to the database something like:

```sql
    SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE username="John_15";
```

Comment: Am I on the wrong path or isnt doing User::where('name', $post->creator)->get(); the same? besides its returning an object and not only avatar, but its the same if i recall correctly?

Comment: Does the object returned contain the avatar field?

Answer (score 0):

First of all this approach will cause a performance and logical issues .. it's better to replace the idea of getting the user by his name by id or make sure the name is unique .. however here is the fix

```
$posts = Post:all();
$user = []; // should be an array because you're looping over it.
foreach($posts as $post) {
  $user[] = User::where('name', $post->creator)->get();
}

return view('welcome')->with('posts', $posts)->with('user', $user);
```

I recommend to make a relationship between the users and post based on a foreign key

## see : [eloquent-relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)